# How to get an MSE for a random forest regression model on the test dataset

Tags: r, regression, random-forest

I have a random forest regression model trained on the training dataset. I want to use it on the test dataset and get the MSE of the forest. How can I do this?

My model is this:

```
fit = randomForest(out.cut$Vir_factor_freq ~ .,out.cut[,-1], importance = TRUE, ntree = 700, replace = TRUE, mtry = 7)
```

Where out.cut is the training data. I have used:

```
pred = predict(fit, out.cut, type="response", OOB = TRUE)
```

Where out.cut is the test data, all well and good I get the predictions but I want to know the accuracy same way you can extract the MSE from the fit model via fit$mse and isolate the ith value.

Comment: Show us what you have done - perhaps then we can help, as it is this sounds like homework.

Comment: @bob1 please ask if it is homework, since you mention it.

Comment: This is not homework, this is a bit of machine learning I am doing on my Masters thesis. Question eddited to provide mroe info

Comment: Mean Squared Error (MSE) is calculated by squaring all of the errors (to make them positive) and then taking the mean value of those squares. It is a single value, so there is no ith value per data point. Root Mean Squared Error  (RMSE) take the square root of that mean, and acts as a sort of average magnitude of error.

Comment: I am refering to the ith value given by the randomForest package which is the average MSE over all previour trees MSEs. That is the value I am looking to find to give me a forest MSE